# ASP.Net Core Web application docker image failing with error -An error was encountered while handling the remote login

Tags: c#, azure, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to test my ASP.Net core Web Application Docker Image locally but getting below error when trying docker run locally

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]   '.AspNetCore.Correlation.AzureADOpenID.qCkwXxlpGF5ynTfvNW2Igg90nqvtstBG9eqgOeGn7Os' cookie not found.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
     An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I am using Https URL. Below is the app settings section:

```
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "Domain": "xxxxx",
   "TenantId": "xxxxx",
   "ClientId": "xxxxx",
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
   "ClientSecret": "xxxxx"
 },
```

When I run the docker from Visual Studio Debugger it seems logs still show this error but the page is not redirecting to signin-oidc and opening correctly .I tried commenting the CallbackPath section but still the site redirects to signin-oidc page and error out .

Here is the Startup.cs code

```
  public static ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            try
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

                services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, (OpenIdConnectOptions options) =>
                {                    
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                    options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;


                });

                
                var redisConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CacheConnection");

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redisConnectionString))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"App setting RTC:CacheConnection is either empty or missing");
                }

                _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString);
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();                
                services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                }).AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions => jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
                
                // Add the Kendo UI services to the services container.
                services.AddKendo();
                services.AddRazorPages();
                services.AddScoped<ICacheService, CacheService>();
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            // Configure Kendo UI
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Ins",
                pattern: "Ins/{*Manage}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Ins", action = "Manage" });
            });s
        }
        private async static Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext ctx)
        {
            var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            const string AZUREADGRAPH_RESOURCE = @"https://graph.windows.net/";
            var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);
            
            string userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var cache = new adowebhub.Controllers.RedisTokenCache(ctx.Options.ClientId, userId);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri), credential, resource: AZUREADGRAPH_RESOURCE);
            ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
        }
```

Below is the docker run command I use

```
docker run --env-file envFileWeb.txt -v c:/temp/aa/:/app/aa  -it --rm -p 8543:8080 --name aspnetcore_sample xxxxx.azurecr.io/xxxx:latest
```

Please suggest how can I resolve this error .

Comment: Add this code snippet `app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
        });` before  `app.UseAuthentication();`.

Comment: Did not worked still redirecting to signin-oidc

Comment: Once check the `Redirect URI` in `Active directory` => `App registrations`

Comment: I have an entry for both signin-oidc  and without that